# Flutter | Sqflite - retrieving elements of queryrow

Tags: flutter, sqflite

this is a function in my dbhelper where it will obtain the filtered result through a rawquery.

```
static Future <List>  getWaterDrank() async {
    final db = await WaterDBHelper.db();
     List result = await db.rawQuery(
        "SELECT * FROM $tableName WHERE ${columnDate} = ?", [dateCurrent]
    );
     print(result);
    List filteredData = result[0];
    print('this is what we are after ${filteredData[2]}');
    
    return result;
  }
```

The problem is that i obtain a list like this

```
[{id: 74, date: Oct 25, 2023, waterDrank: 250}]
```

but i cant get the value of waterDrank - the element i want

I also played around with the use of my model but i cant seem to link my result to the element waterDrank

Comment: the goal is to obtain a single element called waterDrank.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sqflite `Database` `rawQuery` returns a `Future<List<Map<String, Object?>>>;`. Get the list from the future, then the desired map, then iterate through the map's `entries`, then use `firstWhere` dart api checking the element's key with the equality operator against your desired key, waterDrank in this case, then get it's `value`.

**Solution**

```dart
final waterDrank = filteredData[2]
                .entries
                .firstWhere((element) => element.key == 'waterDrank')
                .value;

debugPrint(waterDrank.toString()); // Should print 250
```

---

**Edit**

Above solution is appropriate when iterating through map [entries](https://api.dart.dev/stable/3.1.5/dart-core/Map/entries.html). In this case, It can be shortened with [operator []](https://api.dart.dev/stable/3.1.5/dart-core/Map/operator_get.html) which get's the value of the given key.

```dart
final waterDrank = filteredData[2]['waterDrank']

debugPrint(waterDrank.toString()); // Should print 250
```

Comment: really do appreciate it, cheers

Comment: I've updated the answer with a shorter method.

Comment: i have a problem where the receiver "waterDrank" cant be null however in my case i want it so that it may receive a null value.

Comment: I saw the other question.